# Google Search API filter/sort returning unexpected results

Tags: api, search, filter

I've created an integration with the Google Custom Search API, and the queries look fairly simple but returns unexpected results. My queries are based on this guide: https://developers.google.com/custom-search/docs/structured_search

On my site I've created pagemap with information of my pagetypeid (in which I want to filter by) and a page-ranking (that I want to sort by). These pages are indexed by Google, and when i try to do a simple query, the json object contains the correct values.
i.e:
When I test this in my browser:

https://www.googleapis.com/customsearch/v1?key=[myKey]&cx=[myCx]&q=*&alt=json

Note that I'm searching for q=* (everything).

I receive a list of items with pagemap objects like these:

"pagemap": {

```
"page": [
 {
  "pagetypeid": "12",
 }
],
"pageranking": [
 {
  "score": "5"
 }
],...}
```

I have objects with pagetypeid: 12,3 and a range of other numbers...

The strange part comes when I try to add filtering or sorting.

If I change my query above to this:

https://www.googleapis.com/customsearch/v1?key=[myKey]&cx=[myCx]&q=***+more:pagemap:page-pagetypeid:3**&alt=json

The result from google is without any hits, even though the first query displayed many hits with pagetypeid:3.

If the try the same query but change from pagetypeid:3 to pagetypeid:12, I receive hits as expected.

Why are these queries treated differently?

It's the same way with sorting. Searching for * with sort by score returns 0, but a search with q=test+sort... it returns hits. Is it the combination of how I pass the different parameters to Google?

**Edit:**
Is it possible since this is a test-site with no other traffic other than my own queries - that the response from my request had been cached before it had been indexed, and therefor my query returns an outdated result?

Is it also possible, that when I install this integration on a site with more activity, the
index (by Google) is more frequently updated and as a result, these "bugs" wouldn't appear?

Thanks in advance.